# How to access node from a "parallel" polymer element?

Tags: ajax, dom, polymer

I have some nested polyers elements something like this:
 - pmk-app.html contains app-header.html and app-overview.html
 - app-overview.html contains app-main.html
Inside app-main.html I have an iron-ajax getting some data (from a secured boot spring api) and displaying it into a table. Inside app-header I have a logout button. I want, by clicking this button, to do the logout (I have some issues considering I'm using basic authentication - I'm using a rest endpoint which is returning 401 everytime I call it but this trick looks like is not always functioning) and also to trigger a generateRequest on the iron-ajax in order to display an empty table (because of logging off the rest api is returning a 401) (and to also request user/pass from user).
My problem is how can I access the iron-ajax which is app-main from the app-header? So far I was able by using something like:

```
    _logout: function(event) {
       this.$.outEndpoint.generateRequest();
       document.body.firstElementChild.$.pages.children.overview.root.firstElementChild.$.get_drafts.generateRequest();
}
```

but this construction looks so strange. Is there another way to do this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest trick I like to use is to dispatch an window event and add event listener to the target element like this

app-header:

```
_logout: function(event) {
       this.$.outEndpoint.generateRequest();
       window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('logged-out'));
}
```

iron-ajax:

```
ready() {
  window.addEventListener('logged-out', function(e) {
    //do something here
  })
}
```

Comment: Great option, thanks for it Although I have one dilemma: within the function attached to window.addEventListener it looks it's not an easy and direct path to identify the get_drafts iron-ajax element and I still have to ...descent from window level down to that element.

Answer (score 1):

**Other options and ideas**
This answer is supposed to show the different options that can be used to share states between separated DOM elements. Although the answer by dshukertjr is correct, using the window can get kind of messy when used all over your project.
Same counts for the approach, "properties down, events up", when having deeply nested elements this approach can get confusing as well as tedious as you pass properties/ events through a lot of elements that do not need to know about it.

Another approach would be the usage of Redux. There are many articles and videos by the Polymer team on how to use it. On of them would be here:
 [Project Structure for Using Redux with Polymer 2.0](https://www.captaincodeman.com/2017/07/19/project-structure-for-using-redux-with-polymer-20)

Another interesting article I found and recommend reading when struggling to find the best way for state management is this one:
[Share state between separated DOM elements without Redux](https://www.captaincodeman.com/2017/07/06/managing-state-in-polymer-20-beyond-parent-child-binding)